# Can QListWidget be refreshed after an addition?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm adding an item to a QListWidget, and although I can get the specifics of the item back from the QListQidget, the new item never appears on the screen. Is it possible to refresh the QListWidget to have it update to display newer contents?

```
>>>myQListWidget.addItem("Hello")
>>>print self.myQListWidget.item(0).text()
Hello
```

I'm doing this in Python, but if you have the solution in C++ I can easily convert it.

Thanks!

--Erin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the widget's view by calling `update()` or `repaint()`, the second function is asynchronous and forces widget to update immediately. But the QListWidget should update automatically after insertion without calling any extra functions, if not, then the problem could be that Qt can't process the paint events. Then you have to call `QCoreApplication::processEvents()`, but I am not sure if it is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I'm not seeing that behavior.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
a = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtGui.QListWidget()
w.setWindowTitle('example')
w.show()
w.addItem("test 1")          # shows up
w.addItem("test 2")          # also shows up
```

EDIT: Removed chevrons so the code can be copied/pasted

Comment: I can use a small test case and the widget displays its information correctly. In the more complicated setting it's in now though, that behavior is no longer working as expected, and unfortunately I'm not able to make a small example out of that case to post. The widget clearly knows the information is there, but it's not displaying it- do you know of any way to forcefully display or update the widget?

Comment: @Erin: Are you allowing the main event loop to run (and update the display)?

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar behavior as user671110 with PyQt5 (5.9.2). In my case using the  suggestion from [this qt forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/69481/manually-refresh-qlistwidget-while-inserting/9) worked.

Using the adapted sample code from jkerian:

```py
import sys 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
 a = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
 w = QtWidgets.QListWidget() 
w.setWindowTitle('example') 
w.show()
w.addItem("test 1")                       # Item 1 does NOT show up
w.repaint()                               # Item 1 does NOT show up
QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()    # Item 1 DOES show up
 w.addItem("test 2")                        # Item 2 does NOT show up
QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()    # Item 2 DOES show up
 w.addItem("test 3")                        # Item 3 does NOT show up
a.exec_()                                 # All items shows up
```

This is kind of expected as the GUI is refreshed with event processing. Still THe doc mentioned that repaint() could be use to perform an asynchronous refresh but it does not seems to be working, or I use it wrongly.